# Is there a gold stockpile at "Fort Knox"?

Tags: united-states, economics

I heard an interesting conspiracy theory recently with the basic idea that there isn't a gold stockpile at "Fort Knox" (anymore or ever). With the level of security so great there and reportedly few people having seen the gold, it's an interesting idea and raises the question:

Is there a substantial stockpile of gold at "Fort Knox" (or the Bullion Depository) at present day?

Edit for relevant claim - 
[Brad Metzler's Decoded on History Channel](http://www.history.com/shows/brad-meltzers-decoded) did a show on this.  They were unable to find any evidence that the gold was actually there but had several anecdotes from people who knew people who said there was no actual gold in the vault.

Comment: I've limited your questions to one, because the second was off-topic (and you should really limit your questions to one anyways).

Comment: Actually there is supposed to be an even larger reserve in the NY Federal Reserve Bank.

Comment: I think it is important to note that even if the gold is not in Ft Knox as the government allows everyone to believe, that does not mean that the US Government has sold, given, had stolen the gold.  It would be more likely that the gold was transferred to more secure facilities covertly after all if you do not know where to plan a heist then it makes it harder to actually steal the gold.

Answer (score 20):

Well, there is quite a stockpile at Fort Knox, Alaska (where hundreds of thousands of ounces come out of the ground annually)

http://www.kinross.com/operations/operation-fort-knox-alaska-usa.aspx

As far as the depository is concerned, you'd have to believe the Mint's publications or ask someone to provide classified information to answer your question (not a great idea).

http://www.usmint.gov/about_the_mint/fun_facts/index.cfm?action=fun_facts13

Comment: well said on both counts :) Though I've heard claims that there's no actual gold stored in Kentucky any longer (or that what's there isn't gold at all, or merely gold plated lead or other substitutes) I've never seen incontrovertible evidence to those claims. For now then, I'd go with the official story that there's gold in them there vaults.

Comment: Welcome to Skeptics! Whilst this may technically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Blockquotes are [an excellent way to do this](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/164/315#315).

Answer (score 18):

From [Businessweek - Ron Paul's Fort Knox Fever](http://www.businessweek.com/magazine/content/11_26/b4234039356718.htm) (June 2011)

> [US congressman and three-time Presidential candidate Ron] Paul, who has said he thinks it's possible there is no gold at
> Fort Knox, told *Bloomberg Businessweek* the government is asking the
> American people to trust that all the gold is there, while not
> allowing site visits and not publishing all the data.
>
> **[Eric M. Thorson](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eric_Thorson), the inspector general of the Treasury**, is responsible
> for keeping track of the U.S. Mint's deep storage gold and silver
> reserves. Last September, he **became the first outsider in 37 years to
> be granted full access to the U.S. Bullion Depository, as Fort Knox is
> formally known**.
>
> Thorson tried to reassure Paul that the loot is all there.
> ***I can tell you unequivocally that the gold reserves do exist** in the amounts reported, and the controls over it ensure absolute security*, **he wrote Paul in a letter**.

Thorson didn't do a full audit though, because

> According to Treasury estimates, testing all that gold [*for it's authenticity* ] would take 400
> people working full time for six months to complete and cost at least
> $15 million.

**More:**

- [CNBC - Is Gold in Fort Knox Real? Ron Paul Wants to Know](http://www.cnbc.com/id/43391588/Is_Gold_in_Fort_Knox_Real_Ron_Paul_Wants_to_Know)
- [CNN - Ron Paul worries Fort Knox gold is gone](http://money.cnn.com/2011/06/24/news/economy/ron_paul_gold_audit/index.htm)

Comment: I Think this is probably as close to a real answer as we can hope to get.  Though I am not sure I actually trust the answer given by Gen. Thorson truly addresses the concerns of Congressmen Paul.  
*I can tell you unequivocally that the gold reserves do exist in the amounts reported, and the controls over it ensure absolute security* - This does not say it is in Ft Knox, or how much there actually is in quantity.  The biggest thing the conspiracy buffs point to is that the gold is reported in value rather than weight.  And that the value has not changed in recent time.